# hhline: double vertical line with a partial horizontal line

Tags: hhline

Here is a MWE of a table with a coloured double vertical line. There is a horizontal border at the top which starts at cell 2, and one at the bottom which stops at cell 2. I am using the hhline package.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{p{0.25\textwidth} p{0.25\textwidth}}


\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{white}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}||-}

\multicolumn{1}{r!{\color[RGB]{255, 0, 0}\vrule width 1pt}!{\color[RGB]{255, 0, 0}\vrule width 1pt}}{ Table text } &
\multicolumn{1}{r!{\color[RGB]{255, 0, 0}\vrule width 1pt}}{ More table text } \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]

\hhline{->{\arrayrulecolor{white}}->{\arrayrulecolor[RGB]{255, 0, 0}}|}

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

At the bottom, the horizontal border goes through the double vertical line. But at the top it doesn't. How can I change the central segment of the horizontal border so as to show up black?

[image: table borders]